# Plugin view helper fails on new, edit and show views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a Rails plugin which needs to output a checkbox via a helper. The checkbox appears when placing the helper `startup_exchange_optin('user')` in a scaffolded Users#index view. Placing it in new, edit and show views I get `NoMethodError`:

```
undefined method `startup_exchange_optin' for #<User:0x0000010162c620>
```

File called by `init.rb`:

```rb
# lib/startup_exchange.rb
require 'startup_exchange/startup_exchange_helper'

module StartupExchange
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
 include StartupExchange::StartupExchangeHelper
end
```

The helper:

```rb
# lib/startup_exchange/startup_exchange_helper.rb
module StartupExchange
  module StartupExchangeHelper
    def startup_exchange_optin(object_name, method = 'startup_exchange_optin', options = {}, checked_value = '1', unchecked_value = '0') 
      check_box(object_name, 'startup_exchange_optin', options, checked_value, unchecked_value)
    end
  end
end
```

The plugin is not going to be a gem, which is why the need for `init.rb`. At first I attempted to use `Railtie` but I couldn't get it to initialize. [ActiveSupport.on_load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6636141)
seems to work for at least the index view.

Comment: What is the controller code?

Comment: The controller code is untouched scaffolding.

Comment: I the call to startup_exchang_option is placed in a scaffolded Users#index action, can we see the code where this call is placed into the action?  That would not be untouched scaffolding.

Comment: My miscommunication, I meant view instead of action. I've updated the original question.

Comment: So, again, seeing the view code might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
check_box(object_name, 'startup_exchange_optin'...

#=> undefined method `startup_exchange_optin' for #<User:0x0000010162c620>
```

Your User object doesn't respond to `startup_exchange_optin' method.

Comment: Although the index view was rendering a check_box with an unknown method, the other actions were not. Which confuses me. It's a little clearer to me now that I need a method or column in the User model (or something it `acts_as`) to before a check_box was to be rendered. I cannot simple produce an unattached check_box.